# How to share the "Look Back" video from Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-lookback

On Facebook, there is a [link to view a video](https://www.facebook.com/lookback) looking back on your Facebook history. Apparently, some people have shared this video with their friends, however I and someone else cannot figure out how to do so. This URL is not unique, it's a global URL which shows the video of who's logged in. People say there's supposed to be a "share" link, but there are no links whatsoever. And, I can't share the URL because it would show them their own videos.

How do I share this video with friends on Facebook?

*without using a screen recorder to capture it*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Play through the video once and you should see the "Share Your Movie" button right on top of the video. If you don't see it, refresh the page and it should pop up.

This had happened to me as well. Let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: AH HA! After refreshing, the button suddenly appeared!

Comment: Great! Thanks for confirming! :D

Answer (score 1):

There appears to have been some sort of bug on Facebook where the share button doesn't show immediately. One user reported they had to refresh the page 3 times before the share button finally appeared, which is what I had to do twice. Another user reported no matter how many times they refreshed and no matter what browser they used, the button still wouldn't show. Not sure if this has been officially fixed yet, but when it does show, there should be a green button in the top-right of the video "Share Your Movie", like so:

[image: A Look Back Share Button]

Comment: it's a gradual rollout, I'm sure. I first watched it last night, over 14 hours ago. Still no share.

Comment: and I haz it now.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://m.facebook.com/lookback/share, and you will find a button that allows you to share your Lookback video with others.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is indeed a solution to the problem.